# values of POST method are ignored when the PHP file loads as an jquery modal screen (colorbox)?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have an html page with this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
    $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
    $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
    $(".ajax").colorbox();
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
    $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
      onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
      onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
      onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
      onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
      onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });

    $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
    $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

    $("#cboxFormButton").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();


    $.colorbox({href: $(this).closest('form').attr('action') });


    });

    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    $("#click").click(function(){ 
      $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body style="">
```

and this is my form:

```
<div>
<form action="rrr.php" method="POST" target="_blank" class="">
  <input id="111" name="a" type="hidden" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" id="cboxFormButton" class="button" value="Test">
</form>
</div>
```

and I'm posing to this rrr.PHP file:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['a']));

switch ($_POST['a']) {

    case "1":
        $param1 = "1";
        break;

    case "2":
        $param1 = "2";
        break;

    default:
        $param1 = "other";
}
?>
```

The problem:
in the frame that pops out the rrr.php file, the value "1" that was posted is ignored,
so I Get the result as if a default value was posted.

(I don't want to use the GET function)

What's wrong?

Comment: what is overlay , is it someting like a modal screen>

Comment: yes, i'll change the subject

Comment: I dont understand how does the PHP loads on the modal screen. Does it work without it?

Comment: yes, without the modal it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.colorbox({
href: $(this).closest('form').attr ('action'),
data: {a: $("input#111").val()}
});
```

This should work fine now.

Comment: I get a fatal error. I've posted it right under `<?php`, should I post it somewhere else?

Comment: oh my bad it is var_dump($_POST);

Comment: I get `array(0) { } parameter1 is other`

Comment: if var_dump($_POST); returns array(0){} then your values are not posted to rrr.php

Comment: well, that's exactly what I'm asking - what's hindering them from getting posted? without the modal they do get posted.

Comment: i was trying to understand that correct values are sent in correct format. Since they are not sent at all, we need to check your jquery code.

Comment: thanks, this seems to work but still with a problem, [can you check this new question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962705/two-identical-post-actions-with-jquery-modal-screen-one-works-and-one-doesnt)

Answer (score 0):

The `event.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an element from happening.

In your case:

```
$("#cboxFormButton").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
```

It would prevent your submit button from submitting the form.

---

You dont have much choices you know, since you don't want to use query string and preventing default action, then you have to do the post  in jQuery:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#formID").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $.colorbox({html:data});
        },
        'html');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, but if I take out this line, the whole modal won't work at all; instead of opening a popup layer, it would pass me to complete new url.

Comment: yea I know, and you really dont want query strings

Comment: not sure how to implement this, the other answer seems to work, what's the difference between these methods?